# XYChart in Java Swing application in Netbeans

Tags: java, swing, netbeans

I am creating a Swing Application using the Netbeans GUI editor. Further, I want to incorporate a plot based on the [org.knowm.xchart](http://knowm.org/open-source/xchart/) framework.

I am able to display the plot launching a separate window using the [following code](http://knowm.org/open-source/xchart/xchart-example-code/)

```
double[] xData = new double[] { 0.0, 1.0, 2.0 };
double[] yData = new double[] { 2.0, 1.0, 0.0 };
// Create Chart
XYChart chart = QuickChart.getChart("Sample Chart", "X", "Y", "y(x)", xData, yData);
// Show it
new SwingWrapper(chart).displayChart();
```

How can I incorporate the chart into the swing app rather than launching a separate window?

Comment: You tell us. What does the SwingWrapper class do? I would guess it is just a convenience class that creates a frame and then adds the chart to the frame. So look at the code of the Swing wrapper class and then only use the pieces of the code that create the chart. Then add the chart to your existing frame.

Comment: The SwingWrapper launches a separate window (apart to the main app). My issue is that, when i close that small window, my main window also closes and I have to launch the whole application again.

Comment: The [following code](https://github.com/timmolter/XChart#advanced-example) explains how to include the xchart into a swing app. It works, but what i want to do is to place the chart into an app that I am building in the Netbeans GUI Editor. I do not know how to do that.